# Function in React to check which component should be returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have the following code:

```
const renderModal = location.state?.modal ?? isModal ?? false;

const FormComponent = renderModal ? FormModal : Default;
```

which checks if `renderAsModal` is true & then returns the `Modal` component if so (if not, default component)

But now I have another possible modal, which I can check for like so:

```
const renderCustomModal: boolean =
   location.state?.modal ?? isModal ?? form.key === "UniqueKey" ?? false;
```

How can I update my `FormComponent` assignment to check for `renderCustomModal` as well so my `CustomModal` can be included in the 3 React components that can be returned? Any helpful links/ best practises would be really appreciated.

Comment: Generally you only have one modal open at a time, so I wouldn't do conditional rendering on a modal component. I would use [a portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) for the modal and tuck that (hidden) at the root of your app component. And then, when it needs to be opened, set `isModalOpen` to `true`, and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where I generally break my logic out into a separate function.

```
const pickFormComponent = (arguments, you, need) {
    if (someCondition) return FormModal;
    if (someOtherCondition) return OtherComponent;
    return Default;
}
```

then you can just:

```
const FormComponent = pickFormComponent(and, some, arguments);
```